# Form Norm Data vs. View Data - what's the difference?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

[The documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) says:

```
In any form, the three different types of data are:

    Model data - This is the data in the format used in your application (e.g. an Issue object). If you call Form::getData() or Form::setData(), you're dealing with the "model" data.
    Norm Data - This is a normalized version of your data and is commonly the same as your "model" data (though not in our example). It's not commonly used directly.
    View Data - This is the format that's used to fill in the form fields themselves. It's also the format in which the user will submit the data. When you call Form::submit($data), the $data is in the "view" data format.
```

But I don't understand the difference between norm data and view data. What is the use case for norm data? The next paragraph from the documentation ["So why Use the Model Transformer?"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#so-why-use-the-model-transformer) does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best explanation I have found is in the Symfony's Form class description:

```
<?php

...

namespace Symfony\Component\Form;

use ...

/**
 * Form represents a form.
 *
 * To implement your own form fields, you need to have a thorough understanding
 * of the data flow within a form. A form stores its data in three different
 * representations:
 *
 *   (1) the "model" format required by the form's object
 *   (2) the "normalized" format for internal processing
 *   (3) the "view" format used for display
 *
 * A date field, for example, may store a date as "Y-m-d" string (1) in the
 * object. To facilitate processing in the field, this value is normalized
 * to a DateTime object (2). In the HTML representation of your form, a
 * localized string (3) is presented to and modified by the user.
 *
 * In most cases, format (1) and format (2) will be the same. For example,
 * a checkbox field uses a Boolean value for both internal processing and
 * storage in the object. In these cases you simply need to set a value
 * transformer to convert between formats (2) and (3). You can do this by
 * calling addViewTransformer().
 *
 * In some cases though it makes sense to make format (1) configurable. To
 * demonstrate this, let's extend our above date field to store the value
 * either as "Y-m-d" string or as timestamp. Internally we still want to
 * use a DateTime object for processing. To convert the data from string/integer
 * to DateTime you can set a normalization transformer by calling
 * addNormTransformer(). The normalized data is then converted to the displayed
 * data as described before.
 *
 * The conversions (1) -> (2) -> (3) use the transform methods of the transformers.
 * The conversions (3) -> (2) -> (1) use the reverseTransform methods of the transformers.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 */
class Form implements \IteratorAggregate, FormInterface
{
    ...
}
```

EDIT: Here is a video from the Sf form component (co)author, where he explains data formats and gives an example for a normalized format use -> https://youtu.be/Q80b9XeLUEA?t=7m6s

---

So, basically, every form has a data in three different formats. The first two are: the model data - the data you use in a domain model, and the view data - the data you typically output as a string in HTML or you enter in the form fields before submitting.

Two simple examples would be a TextType and a NumberType.
In the TextType, the model data is the string, and the view data is the string.

In the NumberType, the model data is a float - in your application you are handling float type, and the view data is the localized string.

But, on the other side, if we take a look at a DateType, things are a little bit complicated, because the model data could be string ('YYYY-MM-DD'), an integer (unix timestamp), an array or DateTime object. The view data could be localized string or the array.

[image]

For example, if you want to write an event listener, you can't be sure what data format would you get:

```
class MyDateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add...
            ->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                array($this, 'onSubmit')
            )
        ;
    }

    public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        // BUT WHAT FORMAT DO I GET???
        $data = $event->getForm()->getData();
    }
}
```

Fortunately, Sf form has a third data format - normalized format. That format is static - you always know what you'll get, it is always the same data type!

[image]

```
 public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
 {
     // $data will be DateTime object!
     $data = $event->getForm()->getNormData();
 }
```

Comment: Bless you for taking the time to write a proper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a DateTimeType widget as example.

The model Data is a `Datetime`

The norm data is an `array` ([in the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#data-class))

The view data is a `string` (an input text for example)

Comment: What is the use case for the array? The string must have all the data to convert it to DateTime anyway, so why the intermediary step?

Answer (score 1):

Short explanation / simplification I used to use to remember these kind of things when I started learn symfony forms:

- **Model data**: data in Model/Entity/Whatever form. It's your data source data format
- **Norm data**: data in Form field form. If you have `CollectionType`, for example, you have an array, if you have a `DateTimeType` you have a `DateTime` and so on
- **View data**: data in View form.

Basically if your formats are "consistent" between these "layers", you never(*) need to create a transformer.

Just to make an example of each type:

### Model --> Norm

If you have an entity (**model data**) and you have a `EntityType` field in your form (**norm data**), you don't need to use any transformer

If you have an entity (**model data**) and you have a `TextType` field to represent your entity, you need to use a `ModelTransformer` as your formats are not congruent

### Norm --> View

(*) Any `DateType` or `DateTimeType` has a transformer inserted directly into data type: is used to convert from view (user) date formatting (timezone) and norm (or model) formatting (timezone)

As you can see here, transformation are not only between non congruent data types but also within same type.

You can check also [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/doncallisto/a-journey-into-symfony-form-component)

Answer (score 1):

As a word of warning, you may be bitten by the fact that ViewData can become ModelData and vice versa completely defying explanations provided here. It happens in almost all real word cases.

It's dependent on whether the form is compound or not. Compound forms are the forms that have more than one field, so basically all of them.

See:

> > line 634 send to ViewTransformer mix of view data (from main form) and model data (from children forms). Is it really expected?
>
> Yes it is :) for the reasons I've explained above.
>
> To resume:
>
> Simple form => view data == request data
>
> Compound form => view data == (data_class | array) mapping children model data, using DataMapper.

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/22371#issuecomment-293494324

And:

> > Internally the compound form uses its view data to map the data of the children.
>
> I've done little bit more research:
>
> [As you say the compound option determines if PropertyPathMapper will be used. That's OK.](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/FormType.php#L57)
>   `->setDataMapper($options['compound'] ? new PropertyPathMapper($this->propertyAccessor) : null)`
>
> [Also as you say the Form class is using the mapper to map the view data to the forms. That's OK too.](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Form.php#L385)
>   `$this->config->getDataMapper()->mapDataToForms($viewData, $iterator);`
>
> [Then PropertyPathMapper mapper is setting the data on the forms. Hmm...](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php#L57)
>   `$form->setData($this->propertyAccessor->getValue($data, $propertyPath));`
>
> [Why PropertyPathMapper trough Form is setting ViewData on forms that expect ModelData?](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/FormInterface.php#L120)
>   `public function setData($modelData);`
>
> How did the ViewData changed to ModelData in the mapper? Why ModelData are not mapped on the forms? Why `data_class` is applicable to ViewData and not ModelData where it would make more sense?

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20880#issuecomment-267129575